# Drop down menu for sorting orders by status

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm sorting a list of orders by their status. Right now in my view I have buttons to filter by each category, but i'd like to implement a drop down menu. I'd like to clean up how I sort them too if anyone has any suggestions.

```
admin_controller

def dashboard

@user = current_user
@all_orders = Order.all
if params[:status]
  if params[:status] == "ordered"
    @orders = Order.find_status("ordered")
  elsif params[:status] == "paid"
    @orders = Order.find_status("paid")
  elsif params[:status] == "completed"
    @orders = Order.find_status("completed")
  elsif params[:status] == "cancelled"
    @orders = Order.find_status("cancelled")
  end
else    
  @orders = Order.all
end
end
```

And the view on the dashboard. It's buttons now, we want a menu that drops down.

```
<h3>All Orders</h3>
<%= button_to "Ordered", admin_dashboard_path, method: :get, params: 
{status: "ordered"}, class: "btn btn-small"%>
<%= button_to "Paid", admin_dashboard_path, method: :get, params: 
{status: "paid"}, class: "btn btn-small"%>
<%= button_to "Completed", admin_dashboard_path, method: :get, params: 
{status: "completed"}, class: "btn btn-small"%>
<%= button_to "Cancelled", admin_dashboard_path, method: :get, params: 
{status: "cancelled"}, class: "btn btn-small"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the select box you can do something like this. Create a form but using the get method instead of post so it just adds a query string to the path. I'm including bootstrap classes here just to show how classes can be added.

```
#app/views/admin/orders/dashboard.html.erb
<%= form_tag(admin_orders_path, method: "get", class: "input-group") do %>
  <div class='input-group'>
    <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(['ordered', 'paid', 'completed', 'cancelled']), {prompt: "Select Status", class: "form-control"} %>
    <div class='input-group-btn'>
      <%= submit_tag "Filter by Status", name: nil, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For the controller you don't need to nest it in an if params[:status] block since that appears to be redundant in your example. You could also use a case statement instead of a bunch of if statements but for 4 it's not a big deal. I don't know if find_status is a method you created or you're in an older Rails version but the where method might be preferred.

```
def dashboard
  @all_orders = Order.all
  if params[:status] == "ordered"
    @orders = Order.where(status: "ordered")
  elsif params[:status] == "paid"
    @orders = Order.where(status: "paid")
  elsif params[:status] == "completed"
    @orders = Order.where(status: "completed")
  elsif params[:status] == "cancelled"
    @orders = Order.where(status: "cancelled")
  else    
    @orders = Order.all
  end
end
```

Comment: If this is admin namespace it is probably not a good idea to do current_user.orders.

Comment: Yeah, I put it cuz the questioner had @user = current_user but it really doesn't make sense in an admin space. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

For the sorting, you could do this to DRY your code a little:

```
# admin_controller.rb

def dashboard
  @user = current_user
  @all_orders = Order.all
  @orders = orders(params[:status])
end

private

def orders(status)
  status.present? ? Order.find_status(status) : Order.all
end
```